# Not able to concat property value in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to concat the value which is there in my `version.properties` file but it is not concatenating to the value in my `build.gradle` file.
Below is my code snippet.

```
task dist(type: Zip) {
    baseName = 'ml'
    appendix = 'cicd'

    def props = new Properties()
    file("version.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it)

    into("${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${props.getProperty("VERSION_BUILD")}")
}
```

Comment:  Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you mind to share more from the `build.gradle`? Which task are you executing? Do you receive an error message? I'm sure this will help people to answer your question.

Comment: task dist(type: Zip) {
  baseName = 'ml'
  appendix = 'cicd'
  def props = new Properties()
   file("version.properties").withInputStream { props.load(it) }
  into("${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${props.getProperty("VERSION_BUILD")}") {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have the same type of quotation mark inside a quoted string. Either move the code in the GString to a variable outside, escape the quotes or use single quotes inside the double quotes. I find the first approach more readable.

```
def versionBuild = props.getProperty("VERSION_BUILD")
into("${baseName}-${appendix}-${version}-${versionBuild}")
```